# NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments: Xcode instruments leak

Tags: ios, json, memory-leaks, nsstring, nsdictionary

The following function; "ProcessArrayForscrollView" reads the JSON data that is received by sending a url; "urlProcess" and stores the fetched data values as NSString format in NSMutableArrays.

```
#import "SBJson.h"
#import "SBJsonStreamParser.h"

@implementation AllShowsViewController

NSURL *url = nil;
NSString * arrayDataString;
NSData *dataAllShowsView;
NSError *errorAllShowsView;
NSString *data_stringAllShowsView;
SBJsonParser *parserAllShowsView;
NSArray *data_arrayAllShowsView;
NSDictionary *itemNSDictAllShowsView;
NSMutableArray  *thumbnailImageURLAllShows;
NSMutableArray  *thumbnailShowCountAllShows;

-(void)ProcessArrayForscrollView{
    thumbnailImageURLAllShows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    thumbnailShowCountAllShows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dataAllShowsView = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlProcess] autorelease];
    errorAllShowsView = nil;
    data_stringAllShowsView = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataAllShowsView encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    parserAllShowsView = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
    data_arrayAllShowsView = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[parserAllShowsView objectWithString:data_stringAllShowsView error:&errorAllShowsView]] autorelease];
    for(itemNSDictAllShowsView in data_arrayAllShowsView){
         arrayDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[itemNSDictAllShowsView objectForKey:@"thumbnail_small"]];    //memory leak notification here
        [thumbnailImageURLAllShows addObject: arrayDataString];  
        arrayDataString = nil;

        arrayDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[itemNSDictAllShowsView objectForKey:@"showcount"]];    //memory leak notification here
        [thumbnailShowCountAllShows addObject: arrayDataString];
        arrayDataString = nil;
    }
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload{
    if(thumbnailImageURLAllShows != nil){
        [thumbnailImageURLAllShows release];
        thumbnailImageURLAllShows = nil;
    }
    if(thumbnailShowCountAllShows != nil){
        [thumbnailShowCountAllShows release];
        thumbnailShowCountAllShows = nil;
    }
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

I ran the code to check for memory leaks using Xcode instruments and got leaks at two lines. This leak is notified after I switch from the above viewController; "AllShowsViewController" to any other viewController(having a nib file).Any advices on how to remove the leaks would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think `viewDidUnload` is not guaranteed to be called. The strings are not deallocated correctly because the containers (`NSMutableArray`s) are not. I suggest to try to move your cleanup code for `thumbnailImageURLAllShows` and `thumbnailShowCountAllShows` into `viewDidDisappear` or `dealloc` and see whether there will be memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Halley. Unfortunately even after moving the code to either of the methods, there are still memory leaks at the same lines. Following are the details for the leak:
**Responsible Frame** - NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:
**Responsible Library** - Foundation

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement your setters/getters for your NSMutableArrays like:

```
if (!thumbnailImageURLAllShows) {
        thumbnailImageURLAllShows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

And also insert an exception break point to know where is you code crashing exactly.